Unable to view all columns when freeze and unfreeze all columns in the slickgrid
In a slickgrid with more than 20 columns, if I try to freeze all columns, all of the columns are frozen; when I unfreeze all columns, I am unable to view all columns in the slickgrid; however, if I leave a single column and freeze all other columns after unfreezing all columns, I am able to view all columns in the slickgrid again.
Angular: 17.3.8
Angular-slickgrid: 7.7.0
OS: Windows 10
Node: 18.17.0
NPM: 9.6.7

Scroll horizontally through last column of the angular-slick grid and freeze upto the last column.
Click unfreeze columns on slickgrid menu.

You can now see all the column are not shown in the slickgrid.
What I Tried:- I tried freezing all columns in the list. After that, unfreeze all the column in the angular slick grid. Due to this behavior, unable to view all columns in the Slickgrid.
What I am expecting:- All columns should show while scrolling through the list after unfreeze all columns in the slickgrid.

There might be a misunderstanding of how freezing columns works in SlickGrid, first it only supports left freezing, once columns are frozen then that left section has no horizontal scroll and so only the right side will be scrollable. Because the left section is unscrollable, you cannot freeze columns that are wider (in width total) than the viewport width, it will simply not work correctly. Also another problem that happened in the past is that if the user scrolled to the right before freezing a column, the lib will first scroll back to top/left because columns alignment need position recalc
